# Why can't I flash nethunter.zip and why can't I install an apk file on nexus 5 marshmallow that is transfered from PC?

Tags: nexus-5

I spent like 30 hours to try to install nethunter on nexus 5 but always failed. I tried to root with magisk all procedures following official instructions and succeeded, I also tried to root by flashing SuperSU-v2.82.zip, also succeeded, I also tried to use 'nexus root toolkit' to root and succeeded too. But no matter how many times I root and whatever method I try, whenever it's successfully rooted and SuperSU and BusyBox are granted and installed, I tried to flash the current offial zip file of kali nethunter (of size about 3G), it fails and then I reset to factory img. Whichever version of TWRP I try (3.6.0.9/3.2.3.1/3.0.2.0/2.8.7.2), it just keep reporting the same error msg: "failed to map file 'nethunter....img' ". I have checked SHA256 but the file is intact. And I could flash other zip files like SuperSU.zip.

What's even more annoying is that first I can't download APPs from google play store(sth wrong with the network), second I can't install a single one apk file which I transfer from PC to nexus 5 by USB cable (it constantly reports "can't open file" while any apk I download from a phone browser is installable), or even open a zip file, like there's an invisible barrier around each file that is transfered from PC. Except for the 'nexus root toolkit' method by which I don't have to install APPs, any time I have to install an APP like SuperSU, Magisk, BusyBox or TWRP Manager, I will have to search it in the browser and download the apk to install it, which is very time consuming.

I would be very much obliged if anyone can help solve a problem I met.

All the tutorials I have followed:

Official document: https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/

Officially recommended guide: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-unlock-root-flash-for-nexus-5x.3206930/

Installation with nexus root toolkit video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9QVULNLkug

Installation of Magisk: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html

Comment: You wrote that nethunter image has 3g - when I look at their download page the version for Nexus 5 has 1.7Gb.

Comment: @Robert I checked yes it's 1.7G now, but yestertoday it was about 3G. I'll try the new img

Comment: @Robert The new img worked... This is really weird. I don't know, maybe it's because the latest version of factory img. But I am now having another problem during installation. Thank you, guess this problem is almost solved, except for the fact that I still can't open APK from PC. But I find that nexus root toolkit can help install APK to my phone in its advanced utilities.

Comment: @Robert I have now successfully installed the nethunter on nexus 5 and I can install APKs from PC now. There are several possible reasons, like new img of nethunter, latest version of factory img from official release, utils of "nexus root toolkit", official ES file explorer, etc. I'll try to ascertain the right one next time I install it on another phone. This one has really worn me out, now I just feel relieved that the issue is finally fixed, don't feel like to touch it for now...

Comment: @Robert I forgot to say that I am really grateful for your reply. You actually read my question and checked. I usually don't post questions because for my level of tech, I think I should be able to find the answer somewhere on the internet. But yesterday I felt desperate and crazy, don't know if you know that feeling, like burning from inside out. When I was almost about to give up, I though I might as well resort to stack overflow which helped me many times. Your hint gave me hope to retry and I solved the problem. So thank you very much. (hope this doesn't violate the community rules...)